# Drop Caps: Lettrine package fails to insert line breaks

Tags: lettrine, drop-cap

As you can see, it should spread out over several lines, but does not:

[image]

MWE, the output is the same with `xelatex` and `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%%Lettrine
\usepackage{lettrine}
% lettrine formatting
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0em}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
%\input Romantik.fd
\input Zallman.fd
\newcommand*\initialsfamily{\usefont{U}{Zallman}{xl}{n}}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\initialsfamily}
\begin{document}

\lettrine{T}{his is a test of the lettrine package, designed to show how it fails to insert line breaks.} What can be done about this?

\end{document}
```

I should add that my installation is a bit of a mess, which might have something to do with this.

Comment: That's the default behaviour, the second argument of lettrine is placed in a normal hbox. It is not meant for long text.

Comment: I would not normally use it for a long text, but I am being told it is a convention for fairy tales to have the entire first sentence in small caps, and I am typesetting a fairy tale.

Comment: It would certainly give a nice old-fashioned look, but this is by no means a universal rule for fairy tales looking at some sample images (especially [this page](http://www.themiddlepage.net/2012/06/); many [examples](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=isch&q=fairy+tale+book+page+text) aren't real scans of old fairy tales). So it seems to me you have a choice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple empty second argument followed by `\textsc` works nicely

```
\lettrine{T}{}\textsc{his is a test of the lettrine package, designed to show how it fails to insert line breaks.} What can be done about this?
```

So all we need is a wrapper for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
%%Lettrine
\usepackage{lettrine}
% lettrine formatting
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0em}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\input Zallman.fd
\newcommand*\initialsfamily{\usefont{U}{Zallman}{xl}{n}}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\initialsfamily}

%this is the new stuff
\let\oldlettrine\lettrine
\renewcommand{\lettrine}[2]{\oldlettrine{#1}{}\textsc{#2}}

\begin{document}

\lettrine{T}{his is a test of the lettrine package, designed to show how it fails to insert line breaks.} What can be done about this?

\end{document}
```

[image: Now it works]

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
 \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dropcap}[2]{\lettrine[lines=2,nindent=\z@,loversize=0.15]{\bf#1}{#2}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\dropcap{I}{nternational} Test That is the theory put forth in "Amelia Earhart: The Lost Evidence," a two-hour documentary airing Sunday at 9 p.m. EDT on the History channel. It uncovers records, including this newly revealed photograph that shows what may be a healthy Earhart along with her navigator Fred Noonan, after they were last heard from.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't get that to work, I get `! Undefined control sequence.`.

Comment: I have modified my answer, pl check it now...

Comment: Why not simply `nindent=0pt`? Also, you should use `\bfseries`, `bf` has been deprecated for more than 20 years.

Comment: How does this answer the question? What is the purpose of `\dropcap` supposed to be?